# Can this be simplified?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

$$
e^{-i\frac43\pi n} - e^{-i\frac23\pi n}, n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
I am trying to simplify this but cant. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$
e^{-i\frac{4}{3}\pi n} - e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi n}=e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi n} - e^{-i\frac{2}{3}\pi n}=2i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}3\right)=\left\{\begin{array}\\0&\text{if}&n\equiv0\mod3\\ \pm i\sqrt3&\text{if}&n\equiv\pm1\mod3
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: how did -4/3 become 2/3 ?

Comment: $e^{-i\frac{4}{3}\pi n}=e^{-i\frac{4}{3}\pi n+2i\pi n}$